# How do I use 'this" keyword in an object literal?

Tags: javascript, function, object, this

If I declare both an object and a function in the same object, how do I use `this` to access the object, using the function?
Example:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function () { this.tail = 'torn'; },
    qux: new this.bar() {}
}
// foo.qux instanceof bar => true
// foo.qux.tail = 'torn' => true
```

I can't use `this`, so what should I do?

Comment: When you re-assign the variable, the old value is lost, generally.

Comment: In JavaScript, you can define a variable as both an object and a function.

Comment: Yes, but not at the same time.

Comment: Also please write a title that actually explains what you are asking

Comment: No, you can. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/morningrat/4qLj795h/

Comment: This is no place for trolls.

Comment: You can define a variable as both an object and a function at the same time, just not in the same declaration.

Comment: A function is an object in JavaScript. So technically you can't define a function without defining an object.

Comment: Then why did you say "Yes, but not at the same time."?

Comment: Because that is not the case in other languages, and is often neglected.

Comment: So if every function is an object, how do I use `this` while in the object? Do I have to use it as a function for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't assigning a function and an object to the same variable you are redefining the what the symbol foo is bound to. Everytime you set `foo =` you are binding what is on the right hand side to that symbol.  You can't use `this` to access the function because it is a different object. If you want an object that has a function on it you have to define it like this

```js
var foo = {
     myVal: 123,
     myFunction: function(){ return this.myVal;}
   }
```